# GeoPandas | Plot separate groups of many MultiPolygons

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely, matplotlib

Goal: Plot **8 graphs**; each with **3 legends**, and **1-to-many `Polygons`**.

I have 3 `lists`: `extracted_poly`, `original_poly_flip_y`, `wkt_poly_flip_y`

These represent sources of the same annotations I want to visualise - to find potential discrepancies.

A `list` contains `8` 1-to-many `Polygons`.

e.g. `wkt_poly_flip_y`:

```
[[<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f43a335f400>],
 [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f4338a818b0>,
  <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f4338a81820>],
 [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f43389c0f70>,
  <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f43389c0f10>],
 [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f4338a79d60>,
  <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f4338a79d90>,
  <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f4338a79c70>],
 [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f4338a79f10>],
 [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f43388c50d0>,
  <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f43388c5070>],
 [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f43388c5520>,
  <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f43388c5550>,
  <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f43388c55e0>],
 [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7f43388c53d0>]]
```

---

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(['Extracted Tiles', 'Original Tiles', '.wkt'],
                       geometry=[extracted_poly, original_poly_flip_y, wkt_poly_flip_y]
                      ).plot("geometry", cmap="Blues")
```

Traceback

```
TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: [[<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7f4338b678b0>, ...
```

Converting each `list` to a flat `list` of `8` `MultiPolygons` also errors:

```
extracted_multipoly = [MultiPolygon(polys) for polys in extracted_poly]
```

Traceback

```
TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: [<shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon object at 0x7f4336736580>,
```

Admittedly, I might be getting `geopandas` and `matplotlib` `.plot()` functions muddled up.

---

### Update

**How can I plot all 3 on the graph?**

I've plotted a `list`'s first `MultiPolygon`, without a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`:

```
def plot_multipolygon(multipolygon: list):
    slide_annotations = gpd.GeoSeries(multipolygon)
    slide_annotations.plot(color='red', alpha=0.5)
    
    plt.xlim(0)
    plt.ylim(0)
    plt.show()
```

`plot_multipolygon(extracted_multipoly[0])`:
[image]

`plot_multipolygon(original_multipoly[0])`:
[image]

`plot_multipolygon(wkt_multipoly[0])`:
[image]

Comment: No, I don't have files. In my situation; I can only work with my derived `list` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for slide in list(range(NUM_SLIDES)):
    d = {'col1': ['Extracted Tiles', 'Original Tiles', '.wkt'], 'geometry': [extracted_multipoly[slide], original_multipoly[slide], wkt_multipoly[slide]]}
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs='EPSG:4326').plot(legend=True, alpha=0.5, color=list(mcolors.BASE_COLORS.values()), aspect=1);
```

First Plot:

[image]